# Fast chain rule algorithm

Tags: algorithms

Assume I have two functions $f$ and $g$, with derivatives of $g$ at point $x$ and derivatives of $f$ at point $g(x)$ available.

What is the fastest way of computing derivatives of $f \circ g (x)$ ?

Comment: (d(f(g(x))/dx)(x) = (df/dg)(g(x)) * (dg/dx)(x)

Comment: You don't provide a lot of context here, but using a forward-mode automatic differentiation approach could work well. If you're looking for numerical results and are working in a language that supports user-defined types, generic functions and operator overloading, then I suggest using a "Dual Number" approach. Strictly speaking, it may not be faster than hand-writing the derivatives of your functions (in terms of total operations), but (in my experience) it is less error-prone. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation

Comment: I've addressed this topic in more detail on a different StackExchange site before, so you may be interested in checking it out there. https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/21885/how-does-algorithmic-differentiation-work-and-where-can-it-be-applied/

Answer (score 1):

For real valued function g(x), you can do that as follows,

\begin{equation}
\frac{\textrm{d} f}{\textrm{d} x}=
\frac{\textrm{d} f}{\textrm{d} g}\frac{\textrm{d} g}{\textrm{d} x} \approx
\frac{\textrm{d} f}{\textrm{d} g}\frac{\textrm{Im}\left\{g(x+i\epsilon)\right\}}{\epsilon}
\end{equation}
where $i$ is imaginary number. $\textrm{Im}\{z\}$ gives the imaginary part of the complex number z.

You can implement that in any language which can do operations on complex numbers. You can have very small $\epsilon$, to have small truncation error $O(\epsilon^2)$  and avoid subtractive cancellation error. I don't know how fast it is but is very fast to implement.

For more details see,

*Squire, William; Trapp, George*, [**Using complex variables to estimate derivatives of real functions**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/S003614459631241X), SIAM Rev. 40, No.1, 110-112 (1998). [ZBL0913.65014](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0913.65014).